# ADODB.Connection insert into firebird timestamp field

Tags: vba, timestamp, firebird, adodb

I have the following connection insert string

```
INSERT INTO FACTP01  "(CVE_PEDI,FECHA_DOC,FECHA_ENT,FECHA_VEN) values ('" & vDB(i, 3) & "','" & vDB(i, 4) & "','" & vDB(i, 4) & "','" & vDB(i, 4) & "')"
```

When trying to insert, I get this message

> validation error for column FECHA_DOC,value ***nul***

The value is `2022-07-01 00:00`. The field is timestamp and I'm sure it's not null and it's not repeated, I think the format?

The field is registered as not null and has an ascending index in the base.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Please don't concatenate values into a query string like that, use parameters. In addition, the query as shown is a syntax error. Please provide either your actual VBA code as a [mre], and also print out the query you created using concatenation, so we see the actual query sent to the server.

Comment: Don't use string splicing! it is always fragile and also often is slow. Use parameters. See C# examples on https://bobby-tables.com and on https://www.ibprovider.com/eng/documentation/examples.html